# Folders and files in .apt_generated not automatically created using the plugin id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.11 (JHipster/Mapstruct)"

Tags: jhipster, spring-tool-suite, mapstruct

I created a new JHipster project (with version 4.8.1) and I imported it as Gradle project into Spring Tool Suite 3.9.0.RELEASE

When I run the project, I have this message in the console:

> ```
> > Consider defining a bean of type
> > 'it.andrea.test.service.mapper.PersonaMapper' in your configuration.
> ```

I see that the folder .apt_generated is never created.

In the build.gradle file, I changed the plugin

> `id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.11"`

with

> `id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.8"`

and now it works.

Why?
Regards,
Andrea

Comment: Did you follow instructions http://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse-gradle/ ?

Comment: No, sorry :-( ... but with the older `"net.ltgt.apt"` version "0.8" it was enough to declare `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` in the `build.gradle` file -> run the command `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse` in the prompt -> clean the project by the Eclipse menu `Project -> Clean...`. Instead with the version 0.11, this procedure does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Eclipse to generate MapStruct Mappers using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518161/how-to-get-eclipse-to-generate-mapstruct-mappers-using-gradle)