# How resolve error injecting bean MapStruct in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, mapper

I'm trying to Inject my mapper using mapstruct, but spring doesn't recognize the bean.

**There is my mapper**

```
package com.api.gestioncartera.Services.Mappers;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.api.gestioncartera.Entities.CollectionCompany;
import com.api.gestioncartera.Services.DTO.CollectionCompanyDto;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CollectionCompanyMapper {
    CollectionCompanyDto collectionCompanyToCollectionCompanyDto(CollectionCompany collectionCompany);
}
```

**There is my Service where I'm trying to inject it**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CollectionCompanyServiceImp implements CollectionCompanyService{
    
    @Autowired
    private CollectionCompanyMapper companyMapper;
}
```

**My gradle config**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
 
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'

}
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += [
        '-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true',
        '-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true',
        '-Amapstruct.verbose=true',
        '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring'
    ]
}
```

I also enable enable annotation processing in the IDE
[Properties in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhzwZ.png)

The error is:

*Consider defining a bean of type 'com.api.gestioncartera.Services.Mappers.CollectionCompanyMapper' in your configuration.*

I noticed that I don't have any plugin referencing mapstruct, can be this the problem? Image: [image: Missing plugin]

I'm using Spring Tool Suite 4 (Eclipse) + Gradle 6.8 + SrpingBoot 2.5.6
Please help!!

Comment: Did you check that the implementation for CollectionCompanyMapper is generated correctly, do  a compile in the project and see

Comment: How I can check it?

Comment: Check target/generated_sources folder

Comment: I run the project commenting the inejction, and I check the folder .apt_generated and is empty, MapStruct is not creating the implementation

Comment: I don't have the "target/generated_sources" folder

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518161/how-to-get-eclipse-to-generate-mapstruct-mappers-using-gradle

Comment: I also read this, but I don't have this plugin and if I add this plugin as the library mentioned here https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/  it throws me an error when I build the gradle project :c

Comment: The error is:  Type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile' property 'options.compilerArgumentProviders.apt$0.name' is missing an input or output annotation.

Comment: I download Intellij IDE and it works with any problem

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has its problems with annotation processing.

I solved the issue with my projects using this plugin:

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/

Add this to the top of your gradle plugins.

```
plugins {
  id "eclipse"
  id "com.diffplug.eclipse.apt" version "3.37.1"
}
```

then do a gradle refresh.

If it‘s still not working, run

```
./gradlew eclipse eclipseJdtApt eclipseFactorypath
```

Hope this helps!